# Why i am not getting any output of c++ programs having user defined classes in any ide or editor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, mingw32

When I try to run a c++ programs with user defined class having string and integer attributes in them I am not getting any output.
Below is the code I am trying to execute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Employee
{
public:
  int Age;
  std::string Name;
  void Introduction()
  {
    std::cout << "Name is " << Name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age is " << Age << "\n";
  }
};
int main()
{
  Employee e1;
  e1.Age = 21;
  e1.Name = "EName";
  e1.Introduction();
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have used VS Code and Atom editor to run above code but I am not getting any output.

While this code is giving me desired output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Employee
{
public:
  int Age;
  //std::string Name;
  void Introduction()
  {
    //std::cout << "Name is " << Name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age is " << Age << "\n";
  }
};
int main()
{
  Employee e1;
  e1.Age = 21;
  //e1.Name = "EName";
  e1.Introduction();
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried running the first program through command prompt and I am getting this error:
[image: Error Image]

In my knowledge I have tried providing all the information regarding this issue but still if I missed anything please let me know.

Thankyou.

Comment: I run both pieces of code, and get the output in both cases.

Comment: I ran the code and got the following:
```
-670353260
12
```
A couple of suggestions though: 1. `iostream` is for `cout`; `printf` is in `cstdio`. 2. Pointers shouldn't be output with `%d`, as that's likely the wrong size.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 exactly that is the issue, I am not getting any error while running both cases. The only problem is that whenever I declare a class object my same code doesn't give any output.

Comment: @PierreAbbat I appreciate your suggestion and will do the changes and let you know.

Comment: @PierreAbbat I did the changes you suggested and also removed the pointers as they were not related to this code but the issue still persists. Please go through both edited codes in the question.

Comment: The code is OK, the problem is elsewhere. Set your IDEs aside and use the command line to run the compiler and then run the compiled program. If there is a problem, copy **all** of the text in the terminal emulator and paste it in the question.

Comment: I was able to run the code, but a look at the error posted tells me that either the string library is corrupted or the compiler is unable to find the `main`. I suggest reinstalling the compiler

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I used command line and got an error which I posted in the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @kesarling Ok I will do it and let you know

Comment: It looks like you have a broken compiler installation with more than one version hanging around. You may want to track all them down, remove, and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: As I checked there was indeed a broken compiler installation. I reinstalled the compiler and the program executed successfully. Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Comment: @DishantSingh Great!